# How to refactor out base entity configurations to a separate class in Entity Framework Core Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, fluent

I am porting over a website I maintain to .Net6 in the next few months. I have upgraded/updated the domain model and am now working on the Fluent API to define my EntityType Configurations.

There used to be a Properties method off modelBuilder where you could define your BaseEntity property configurations ONCE in the OnModelCreating method. Apparently, that didn't make it into EF Core Fluent API.

Base entity class

```
public abstract class EntityBase : IdBase, IEntity
{
    //private setter = immutable so it will only be created once   
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;      
    public string CreatedByUserId { get; private set; } = "";

    // use DateTime.UtcNow when modifying
    public DateTime DateModified { get; private set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;   
    public int ModifiedCount { get; private set; } = 0;           
    public string ModifiedByUserId { get; private set; } = "";
    public List<DomainEventBase> DomainEvents = new();
}
```

For example:

```
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "CreatedByUserId").Configure(x => x.HasMaxLength(Common.Constants.GuidColumnLength));
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "ModifiedByUserId").Configure(x => x.HasMaxLength(Common.Constants.GuidColumnLength));
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "DateCreated").Configure(x => x.HasColumnType(Common.DateConstants.SqlDataTypeColumn));
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "DateModified").Configure(x => x.HasColumnType(Common.DateConstants.SqlDataTypeColumn));
```

Which I refactor out to a method called ConfigureBaseEntityProperties.

I am not finding a way to accomplish this in EF Core for .Net6. Ideally I would prefer to do it as EntityTypeConfiguration but I can't find a way to get that to work either.

Answer (score 1):

you can still do it like this:

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(type => type.GetProperties())
                .Where(property => property.Name == "CreatedByUserId"))
{
     property.SetMaxLength(Common.Constants.GuidColumnLength);
}
```

Comment: Without testing as of yet, I would need to figure out how to return all configurable properties, to configure them at once or else that GetEntityTypes would have top be run for every property. But I'm guessing/speculating their is an easier way to do this.

Comment: @dinotom I'm not sure what you mean by "how to return all configurable properties" - GetEntityTypes returns all Types known to EF so the above code retrieves all properties of all Types known to EF and then filters/configures them

Comment: If there are five properties, which there are, I put the class in the original post, there would need to be five "where" calls. I can modify this code to make it work, (.Where(property => property.Name.Contains("UserId")) that will set the two string properties) and had done something similar already, but my question revolves around whether or not there is a direct replacement for the Properties method that used to exist before EF Core, which obviously makes what I'm trying to do extremely easy.

Comment: @dinotom I'm sorry but I still do not understand your question. In your post you show the code you used before EF Core which also contained multiple where clauses (one for each property) - you could just put my code from above into an Extension Methode, call it "Properties" and you would have a direct, reusable replacement for the old method

Comment: My point is, that for each property that loop would have to be run. I can and did, have a similar for loop running which searched for the unique parts of the name properties' and also for the DateTime properties in that class and then defines them, but even that requires 2 runs through the loop.